# chrome: "ghost" width of floated elements inside inline block

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

test case http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hFumw.
Works fine in all browsers except chrome. In chrome width of `.container` is calculated like `.child.one` elements are not floated. Is there any way to fix this behaviour?
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  header
  </div>
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  .child {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  .one {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
    background:yellow;
  }
  .header {
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

**UPD:**

```
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

is not acceptable in my particular case.

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question in addition to the link.  Links are great but the question should be self sufficient.

Comment: I found another "dirty" solution: add empty `<div></div>` between every floating div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following CSS seems to work fine in Chrome and FF. See header declaration.

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  .child {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  .one {
    float: left;
    clear:left;
    background:yellow;
  }
  .two {
    float: right;
    margin-left:0px;
    clear: right;
  }
  .header {
    background:blue;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: sad, but floating header is not acceptable in my particular case.

Comment: Can you tell us why is that?

Comment: I could understand your concerns if it was a header tag (e.g. <h1>), but it's just another div.

Comment: In project there were some fragile positioning tricks, relying on this block. Finally I managed to use your solution, thank you! Now I'm just curious, why webkit is acting like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css to `.header`

```
clear:both;
float:left;
width:100%
```

Comment: Sad, but floating header is not acceptable in my particular case.